# Quoting a string for csh

Tags: python, csh, tcsh, quoting

For the purposes of this question, by "csh", I mean tcsh.

I am aware of the standard advice to avoid csh for programming. However, sometimes ones needs to interact with existing csh code, and then it may be necessary to quote a string for csh.  To put it another way, the problem is how to represent an arbitrary byte string in csh syntax.

Is the following csh_escape_arg function correct?  That is, does there exist a string that, were it added to the list of strings in the test, would cause that test to fail?  If there is such a string, how can I fix my function so that all strings pass the test?

```
import string
import subprocess
import unittest

# Safe unquoted
_safechars = frozenset(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '@%_-+:,./')

def csh_escape_arg(str_):
    """Return a representation of str_ in csh.

    Based on the standard library's pipes.quote
    """
    for c in str_:
        if c not in _safechars:
            break
    else:
        if not str_:
            return "''"
        return str_
    str_ = str_.replace("\\", "\\\\")
    str_ = str_.replace("\n", "\\\n")
    str_ = str_.replace("!", "\\!")
    # use single quotes, and put single quotes into double quotes
    # the string $'b is then quoted as '$'"'"'b'
    return "'" + str_.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"

def csh_escape(args):
    return " ".join(csh_escape_arg(arg) for arg in args)

def get_cmd_stdout(args, **kwargs):
    child = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
    stdout, stderr = child.communicate()
    rc = child.returncode
    if rc != 0:
        raise Exception("Command failed with return code %d: %s:\n%s" % (rc, args, stderr))
    else:
        return stdout

class TestCsh(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hard_cases(self):
        for angry_string in [
            "\\!\n\"'`",
            "\\\\!\n\"'`",
            "=0",
            ]:
            out = get_cmd_stdout(["tcsh", "-c", csh_escape(["echo", "-n", angry_string])])
            self.assertEqual(out, angry_string)

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Edited the code to fix the problem with '=' pointed out by Mark Armstrong.

Answer (score 2):

1) For tcsh you would also need to quote "=" to prevent directory stack substitution.
2) I think your algorithm would also have a problem with a string with an unpaired double-quote.
3) An alternative would be to write your target script in such a way that the string is not subject to substitution.  For instance by writing your string to a file, and then having your script read the string from the file into a variable, like

```
set a = `cat file`
```

and then use the variable as needed.

Comment: Thanks re =.  That can be fixed by removing that character from the "safe" list.  As for unpaired double quotes, can you give an example?  Strings like (in Python syntax) '"', '"foo', and 'foo"' all pass the test in my question already.

Comment: on second thought it seems fine